# ember.js: transitioning to the same route creates a stack overflow issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js

this is my route:

```
photo: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/photo/:photo_id',
      showPhoto: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.photo'),
      connectOutlets: function(router, photo) {
        console.log("TEST");
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('photo', photo);
      },
    })
```

Within my PhotoView, I have a few places, where i have to show "related photos", whose thumbnails should also be clickable, so I have this

```
<a {{action showPhoto this href=true}}> ...photo... </a>
```

However, if I click on the links afterwards, I get a stack overflow error. How do I resolve this? I really need to route to the same view, but with new data

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be helpful. By providing that, you'd make it easier for someone to debug

Comment: For a firstbstep, I would recommend to enable logging in the router. Where you set the route state put this line there: enableLogging: true. This would log states into browser console and would help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`action showPhoto this href=true` with

`action showPhoto photo href=true`

without jsfiddle it is hard to check my answer.